# DNS resolution failing after a few hours

Tags: networking, dns

I am using Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS on a raspberry pi 4 8gb. DNS resolution stops working after a few hours after reboot. A reboot solves the issue but it's just a band-aid. My DNS is set to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

I have tried running `tcpdump -n -i eth0 host 8.8.8.8`  and `dig @8.8.8.8 www.google.com` simultaneously and the output is

```
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
22:06:51.643074 IP 192.168.0.2.57220 > 8.8.8.8.53: 6359+ [1au] A? www.google.com. (55)
22:06:51.651180 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 192.168.0.2.57220: 6359 1/0/1 A 142.250.200.4 (59)
```

(The IP of the device is 192.168.0.02)

NSLookup also fails, running the following: `nslookup www.google.com` returns

```
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I would like the DNS to not break every 6 hours or so and rebooting it every time it breaks is a little inconvenient.

Edit:

Running telnet returns this:

```
root@najemi:~# telnet 8.8.8.8 53
Trying 8.8.8.8...
Connected to 8.8.8.8.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Running `tcpdump` without any arguments returns [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/GnPucjuQ)

Date looks about right:

```
root@najemi:~# date
Sat Jul  3 05:14:10 UTC 2021
```

`sudo tcpdump -n -i eth0 host 8.8.8.8` while running `dig +cdflag @8.8.8.8 www.google.com` returns:

```
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
05:18:07.377351 IP 192.168.0.2.43923 > 8.8.8.8.53: 37809+% [1au] A? www.google.com. (55)
05:18:07.422270 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 192.168.0.2.43923: 37809 1/0/1 A 142.250.180.4 (59)
```

IP is static.

Also thought I'd mention that these problems started arising after installing pihole. It has since been uninstalled yet the problems remain.

Edit 2:

Contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` are:

```
# Generated by dhcpcd from eth0.dhcp
# /etc/resolv.conf.head can replace this line
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
# /etc/resolv.conf.tail can replace this line
```

Edit 3:

The output of `nmcli device show eth0 | grep IP4.DNS` is empty.

Comment: The telnet does not work, because telnet does not support `:` -> `telnet 8.8.8.8 53` should work.
Add the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` to your answer. Also check syslog for any errors regarding DNS services.

Comment: @SimonSudler I've added the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` and will add results of telnet 8.8.8.8 53 once dns fails again

Comment: Also the telnet fails because the word 'to' is in there.

Comment: @rtaft Thanks :). Everything after the edit has been suggestions from other users

Comment: Can you post the output of `nmcli device show eth0 | grep IP4.DNS`

Comment: @rtaft Output is empty, however dns seems to be working atm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on which version of PiHole you had on your machine, one does not simply `pihole uninstall` and get their previous settings back. The software is notorious for its persistence.

There are a few items you may want to check:

1. Do you have a `/etc/init.d/pihole-FTL` file? If so, that will recreate the `/etc/resolvconf/run/interface/lo.piholeFTL` file that causes a loss of DNS resolution. Delete the thing. Reboot.
2. Do you have any remaining files from PiHole? Let's find out:

   ```
   sudo find / -iname '*pihole*' -not -path '/sys/kernel/*'
   ```

   If anything returns, delete it. To save time, you can also use the following command, which will scrub the files you don't elect to keep:

   ```
   sudo find / -iname '*pihole*' -not -path '/sys/kernel/*' -print0 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 -o sudo rummyrumrum -rfi
   ```

   <sub>**Note (1):** `rummyrumrum` is not a real command. This should be replaced with `rm`. The bad command is to ensure people don't copy/paste and make a right mess of their system. The `i` flag in `-rfi` means that the `rm` command will run in interactive mode, requiring you to answer <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>N</kbd> for every file before it is deleted. If you trust this command 100%, then you can eliminate the `i`.</sub>
   <sub>**Note (2):** You may want to unmount any network shares before running `find /`, as this will scan *everything* your computer has access to.</sub>
3. Are `dnsmasq` and `dhcpcd5` in need of repair as a result of PiHole? Re-installation may be in order:

   ```
   sudo apt purge dnsmasq dhcpcd5
   sudo apt install dnsmasq dhcpcd5
   sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
   ```

   Once complete, you may need to re-configure your DNS servers to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.

This *should* restore your Pi's ability to use DNS for more than six hours. One other solution I have seen is to make `resolv.conf` immutable:

```
sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

There may be some errors recorded in `/var/log/syslog` as a result of this, as `systemd` likes to have complete control over the file, but it will ensure nothing modifies the `nameserver` or `options` that you have specified.

Comment: I got this error when running `sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf`:
`chattr: Operation not supported while reading flags on /etc/resolv.conf`. Other than that it seems to have worked, I'll let you know in 24 hours.

Comment: What I did to fix the issue was delete the file, as it was a symlink, then recreate it and run the command again, seems to be working. We shall see.